# kio sftp does not work but fish works

Tags: kde, gentoo, sftp

If I try to initiate an `sftp` connection from dolphin (or konquerer),
it tells me the password is wrong and asks me for the correct password.

> Incorrect username or password  Do you want to retry?

I have tried 4 different servers with the same response. All 4 serevrs worked with an earlier version of KDE.

If i use `fish` instead, it works.

I have tried starting dolphin from a consle, but got no error messages there.

1. If there is a real error message, where/how do i find it?
2. How can I get `sftp` to start working again?

Info about my KDE:

```
$ uname -a
```

> Linux rito.work.puggan.se 2.6.38-gentoo-r6 #2 SMP Thu Jul 14 14:36:14 CEST 2011 i686 AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux

```
equery list kdelibs kdebase-kioslaves kioclient dolphin -p
(I = Installed, P = Avaible in Portage)

 * Searching for kdelibs ...
[-P-] [  ] kde-base/kdelibs-4.7.4:4
[-P-] [ ~] kde-base/kdelibs-4.7.4-r12:4
[IP-] [  ] kde-base/kdelibs-4.8.3:4
[-P-] [ ~] kde-base/kdelibs-4.8.4:4

 * Searching for kdebase-kioslaves ...
[-P-] [  ] kde-base/kdebase-kioslaves-4.7.4:4
[IP-] [  ] kde-base/kdebase-kioslaves-4.8.3:4
[-P-] [ ~] kde-base/kdebase-kioslaves-4.8.4:4

 * Searching for kioclient ...
[-P-] [  ] kde-base/kioclient-4.7.4:4
[IP-] [  ] kde-base/kioclient-4.8.3:4
[-P-] [ ~] kde-base/kioclient-4.8.4:4

 * Searching for dolphin ...
[-P-] [  ] kde-base/dolphin-4.7.4:4
[IP-] [  ] kde-base/dolphin-4.8.3-r1:4
[-P-] [ ~] kde-base/dolphin-4.8.4:4

emerge -pv

[ebuild   R    ] kde-base/kdelibs-4.8.3  USE="3dnow acl alsa bzip2 fam handbook mmx nls opengl (policykit) semantic-desktop spell sse sse2 ssl udev udisks upower (-altivec) (-aqua) -debug -doc -jpeg2k -kerberos -lzma -openexr -test (-upnp) -zeroconf" 0 kB
[ebuild   R    ] kde-base/kdebase-kioslaves-4.8.3  USE="bzip2 exif handbook sftp (-aqua) -debug -lzma -openexr -samba" 0 kB
[ebuild   R    ] kde-base/kioclient-4.8.3  USE="(-aqua) -debug" 0 kB
[ebuild   R    ] kde-base/dolphin-4.8.3-r1  USE="handbook semantic-desktop (-aqua) -debug -thumbnail" 0 kB
```